# Open a modal in bootstrap but also call a controller action to populate the form, laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I have a modal that I open and it contains a form for creating a new post for a blog. Nothing difficult at all. When I click create, a controller action is called, the post is then created and so on and so forth.

This is all awesome.

But now what I want to do is when I click the "edit" I want the same modal to open, but I want the inside form populated with said post. Is there away on the modal trigger to call a controller action , open the modal and then do I want from there?

What I have so far for opening the modal is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createNewPost">Create Post</a>

// Which calls:

<div class="modal fade" id="createNewPost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createNewPost">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="createNewBlog">Create a new post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @include('blog.posts.create')
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// Note the include (from above):

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'create-new-post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('title', 'Post Title', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::text('title', '', array('placeholder' => 'sample title', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('content', 'Post Content', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::textarea('content', '', array('placeholder' => 'some content', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('tags', 'Post Tags', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::text('tags', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'data-role' => 'tagsinput')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('categories', 'Post Categories', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::text('categories', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'data-role' => 'tagsinput')) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{ Form::hidden('blogId', $blog->id) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            {{ Form::submit('Create', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So this works really well for creating a blog. Now I want to do the same thing but this time I want to call a controller action to then return something so I can use it in the modal view and populate said form with it.

**Ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by using Form Model Binding.. check out the laravel docs or this link https://scotch.io/quick-tips/laravel-form-model-binding